# Italicize and color legend manually for different graphs using same labels and colors

Tags: colors, label, legend, graphing

I am trying to create multiple graphs that share the same legend. 
I have found many ways to combine multiple graphs and it seems that `ggarrange` has the ability to create one shared legend for all that is supposed to be unique.
However I am having some problems when graphing since a few of the graphs do not have the same phyla (what defines the legend colors) present, but I would like them all to be the same colors throughout all of the graphs so the combined legend will have the correct colors.
For just one graph I would assign a color to the label manually like below

```
labs<-c("Arthropoda"="#FF66CC"
        ,"Cercozoa"="#FF6000")
```

and plot with the addition of `scale_fill_manual(values=labs)` and this seems to work

then I modified it so I could have portions of them italicized.

```
labsPhylum <-c('expression(paste(italic("Arthropoda")))'="#CC0000"
              ,'expression(paste(italic("Cercozoa")))'= "#FF6000"
             ,'expression (paste("unknown", ~italic("Eukaryota")))'= "#990000")`
```

However when I create a plot using `ggplot` and `scale_color_manual()` using the labsPhylum that I think should be italicized and colored I plot an empty graph with this warning so there is something vital I am not understanding here.

```
ggplot(data=sigtab_dil, aes(x=Species, y=log2FoldChange, color=Phylum))+ 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=labsPhylum)

    Warning message:
    Removed 9 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Could someone please help me figure out where I am going wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question

I realized I had to make separate vectors for breaks, labels, and values rather than combining them.

In short

```
colsPhylum <-c("Arthropoda"="#CC0000"
              ,"Cercozoa"= "#FF6000"
              ,"Chlorophyta"= "#CC9900"

labsPhylum <-c(expression(paste(italic("Arthropoda")))
               ,expression(paste(italic("Cercozoa")))
               ,expression(paste(italic("Chlorophyta ")))

breaksPhylum <-c("Arthropoda", "Cercozoa","Chlorophyta", "Choanozoa"
               ,"Ciliophora"
               ,"Cryptista"
```